# Xamarin Forms FAB with images

Tags: android, xamarin

Does anyone know how to create a FAB in Xamarin Forms with images that flyout, like in the My Disney Experience app for Android?  Its pretty amazing:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with FAB?

Comment: Sorry, Floating Action Button.  In the post image, its the "X" menu item at the bottom of the mobile screen.  When you tap it, the images animate out, and they themselves are tappable menu items.  This is a link to a generic FAB for Xamarin Forms, which doesn't have these features as far as I can tell  https://www.nuget.org/packages/FAB.Forms/